# Read URL from text file and then download the file as an exe. Javascript

Tags: javascript, file, variables, url, download

I want to download a file from a URL in a txt file.
I have a text file at

```
    https://server.com/file/downloadlink.txt
```

and that txt file contains my current EXE download URL.

The URL that the txt file contains is

```
    https://server.com/file/downloadv1.exe
```

I also have a php webpage that will take the URL from the txt file and download from that specified URL.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).  Something like this:

```
fetch('https://example.com/file/downloadlink.txt').then((res) => {
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(res.statusText);
  }
  return res.text()
}).then((data) => {
  // Parse your text file here
});
```

Not sure why you wouldn't just redirect from that URL though....